# chrome://plugins URL no longer works

Tags: google-chrome, flash, plugins

In setting up a new Windows 10 laptop, I installed the latest version of the Chrome browser.

Anyway, when I go to the chrome://plugins URL, instead of showing the plugins settings page, it gives me the message:

```
This site can’t be reached

The webpage at chrome://plugins/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_URL
```

Here's the version info for Chrome, from chrome://version:

```
Google Chrome   57.0.2987.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Revision    11f66db67ea1f20d200d6f9add50fc1c345d71f7-refs/branch-heads/2987@{#832}
OS  Windows 
JavaScript  V8 5.7.492.65
Flash   25.0.0.127 C:\Windows\system32\Macromed\Flash\pepflashplayer64_25_0_0_127.dll
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.110 Safari/537.36
Command Line    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
```

My question is, does anyone know why the chrome://plugins URL no longer works, and how can I get to its current equivalent, if at all?

The reason I need to access this is that I'm trying to get the debug Flash player working. I think I have to disable the pre-installed non-debug one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

chrome://plugins was removed in Chrome 57. [Here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=615738) is the job where it was removed.

From the linked job:

> Objective: Remove the chrome://plugins page, moving configuration for the last remaining plugin, Flash Player, to it's own explicit place in content settings (including an option, in settings, to disable).
>
> Rationale: This change should make the controls for Flash Player more discoverable, in settings (i.e. most users probably know what Flash is, but not what a "plugin" is), and will consolidate modes related to Flash Player (e.g. Plugin Power Savings mode), into a single location.
>
> Supporting Rationale: Since we've deprecated NPAPI, Flash Player is now our last remaining plugin (i.e. 3rd party binary modules).  Those remaining "plugins" (PDF, CDM, etc...) started life as 3rd party code, but have since been built and maintained by Google... and at this point are effectively just specialized libraries for Chrome.

Comment: Thank you. I would add that the URL where the Flash plugin info is displayed is: 

    chrome://flash

I am able to verify that it's using the Adobe plugin from this line:  
  
Flash plugin 25.0.0.127 C:\Windows\system32\Macromed\Flash\pepflashplayer64_25_0_0_127.dll